# saving NSMutable Array Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, xcode4.2

I have a UITableView that is populated using a NSMutableArray . I am using xcode 4.2

the data in the NSMutable array stays in case I switch applications but it gets erased in these two cases :
1-the user switch view and come back .

2-the application is completley closed (i.e. the user double click on the Main button and remove it from the list of running application)

here is the code that I am using

```
-(NSString *)dataFilePath{

    NSString *dataFilePath;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    dataFilePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test App-Info.plist"];
    return dataFilePath;

}

-(void)saveData{
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:[data copy] toFile:[self dataFilePath]];
}

- (void)loadData
{
    data = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:self.dataFilePath];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
  ...

    //saving the history

    NSArray *archivedArray =[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self dataFilePath]];
    if (archivedArray == nil) {
        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else {
        [self loadData];
        [mainTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I am missing something

Thanks

Edited :

the save data function is loaded in two  locations :
1- the app that I am developing scans QR codes , so save data is called in the following function :

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
.... 
   id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
    [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results){
        // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
       break;
    }

    if(!symbol) 
        return;

    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
    theBarcodeString = symbol.data;

    //adding the string to the list

    [data addObject:theBarcodeString];
    [self saveData];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
    [self endText];
    stringLabel.text=theBarcodeString;

...
}
```

it is also called in when the data is edited :

```
    -(IBAction)editTable{
        UIBarButtonItem *leftItem;
        [mainTableView setEditing:!mainTableView.editing animated:YES];
        if (mainTableView.editing) {
            leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(editTable)];
        }
        else {

            leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editTable)];

    }

    [self saveData];
    [mainTableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: so where from do you save your data?

Comment: I might be wrong (I am new to App developpment ) but According to the code , the data is saved in dataFilePath in Test App-Info.plist (the project plist) , should this be changed to something else ?

Comment: i mean in what methods do you call your saveData method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into the following calls:

```
applicationDidEnterBackground
applicationWillEnterForeground
applicationDidBecomeActive
applicationWillTerminate
```

They are all methods of UIApplication.  Your needs will dictate which of the above store and restore your data depending on when it should happen.

Comment: I changed the name of the file from "Test App-Info.plist" to "text.txt" and I found out that nothing is written in it .... I don t think it is normal , any suggestion ?